# How to Synchronize X Axis of Selected Panes in Zedgraph?

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I'm trying to synchronize X-Axis of selected panes in the Zedgraph,

Currently I've *three* panes:

[image]

with the help of the follwoing property I can synchronize X-Axis of all the available panes:

```
zedGraphControl1.IsSynchronizeXAxes = true;
```

---

but I want to synchronize just **Pane-1 & Pane-3**, is it possible?

Many Thanks for your time...:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. List item

Yes it is.

Basically, you have to hook to the ZoomEvent, then catch the pane which has been panned or zoomed, using `FindPane`, apply its Scale Min and Max properties to the others, then do an `AxisChange` if some other Scale properties are set to `Auto`.

Assuming the GraphPane object you want to exclude is `excludedGraphPane`

```
void zedGraphControl1_ZoomEvent(ZedGraph.ZedGraphControl z, ZedGraph.ZoomState oldState, ZedGraph.ZoomState newState)
{
    GraphPane pane;

    using (var g = z.CreateGraphics())
        pane = z.MasterPane.FindPane(z.PointToClient(MousePosition));

    // The excludedGraphPane has to remain independant
    if (pane == null || pane == excludedGraphPane)
        return;

    foreach (var gp in z.MasterPane.PaneList)
    {
        if (gp == pane || gp == excludedGraphPane)
            continue;

        gp.XAxis.Scale.Min = pane.XAxis.Scale.Min;
        gp.XAxis.Scale.Max = pane.XAxis.Scale.Max;
        gp.AxisChange(); // Only necessary if one or more scale property is set to Auto.
    }

    z.Invalidate();
}
```

Of course, because the synchronization is done manually now, you need to set

```
zedGraphControl1.IsSynchronizeXAxes = false;
```

Comment: @Laurant, Thanks for the effort, I didn't quite understand the `if` condition `if (pane == null || gp.Tag == "Excluded pane")`, I dont think it'll work.. could you calrify `gp.Tag` property please?

Comment: The tag thing was not a good idea. I changed this and put a direct comparison with the "excluded" GraphPane reference instead.

Comment: @Laurant, am I missing something?? Please correct me if I'm wrong! the variable `gp` in the `if` condition doesn't have any definition prior to it..

Comment: Hi @San', yes it is: gp is defined in the 'foreach' loop.

Comment: Oops, I just realize I forgot to mention that zedGraphControl1.IsSynchronizeXAxes should be set to 'false'... I updated my answer.

Comment: @Laurant, I still can't understand the variable `gp` that you've used outside the foreach loop, `gp` within foreach loop is valid & I have no issues with it, but I'm talking about the one which is used outside the foreach loop[just under the comments section].

Comment: Apologizes! You're right, it just jump out now. It's fixed: the right test is pane == excludedGraphPane